# Cannot alert after checking for null value

Tags: javascript, html, null, local-storage, alert

I am new to Javascript.
I would like to redirect the user to page B when they load page A but there isnt any local storage ( page A needs to load info from local storage )

The code below checks if there is a local Storage existed. If there isnt any local storage and the person clicked page A,the desired outcome should be first alert something then redirects, but the following code only redirect instantly.
Can anyone shows me the correct way of getting the desirable outcome?
I can only use javascript but cannot use jquery. Thanks a lot!

```
   function loadpage(){ //runs when the browser first loaded
        var mov = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('one'));
        if (mov == null || mov == "") {
            alert('Please choose object')
            window.location = "object.html"
        }else{
           getdetail();
           gentable();
           retrivedata();
           document.getElementById("proceed").disabled = true;
        }
   }
```

Comment: ending semicolons are optional in JS

Comment: Your code works in my browser. Maybe your browser isn't showing alerts. Have you tried another browser yet?

Comment: your code work in mine too!! there is no problem . but for more sure check u call the loadpage() or not!!